# Bluetooth Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 hci_conn_timeout+0x75/0x2a0

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb, bluetooth

I am having issues with my Bluetooth connection dropping constantly. The chipset is a Broadcom BCM20702A0 (PLUGABLE USB 2.0 BLUETOOTH ADAPTER http://goo.gl/h42upl)
Before and after pairing the device appears then disappears every 3 seconds. I have checked through many forums however yet to find a solution.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, error & wifi dongle details below:

(some of) output from dmesg | grep blue:

```
[62829.136734] WARNING: CPU: 4 PID: 7002 at /build/linux-lts-utopic-3gKELT/linux-lts-utopic-3.16.0/net/bluetooth/hci_conn.c:296 hci_conn_timeout+0x75/0x2a0 [bluetooth]()
```

Wireless Info (http://goo.gl/t5FPss):

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 16 Jan 2016 11:35 GMT +0000

Booted last: 15 Jan 2016 18:16 GMT +0000

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-57-generic #77~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 23:20:00 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V [8086:153b]
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e091] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 11b0:6348 ATECH FLASH TECHNOLOGY 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045b:0210 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2516:0011  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045b:0209 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

mxm_wmi                13021  0 
snd_soc_rt5640         93124  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         13037  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          200418  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_pcm               104112  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
wmi                    19193  1 mxm_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:18 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth1' [IF]>  
      inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth1' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:985193 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:704578 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1173587124 (1.1 GB)  TX bytes:101507245 (101.5 MB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7300000-f7320000 

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home.gateway

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1311     1  0 Jan15 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: <MAC address> ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Bluetooth
  Driver:            bluez
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no

  Capabilities:

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            alx
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: eth1  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth1' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.101
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.254

    DNS:             192.168.1.254

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/London (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

eth1      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x8086:0x153b (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth1' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
# PCI device 0x1969:0xe091 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   29.884969] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[   29.890551] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   32.847170] e1000e: eth1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   32.847197] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[62390.180812] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware hci_ver=06 hci_rev=153a lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=220e

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I have narrowed the issue down to BlueProximity 1.2.5-6. Once removed the issue was resolved. I also tested on Ubuntu 15.04 and this has the same issue when BlueProximity is installed, to rule out the Kernal bug.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a kernel bug (e.g. [RedHat bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1144842)), the report there says:

> The error reported by me at 2015-02-10 was running on a
>   3.17.8-200.fc20 kernel.
>
> I have later upgraded to 3.18.5-101.fc20 and 3.18.7-100.fc20.  Indeed,
>   I did not have the same bug again, since.

So suggest [trying a later kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade).

Comment: I noticed on comment 6 (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1144842#c6) the user removed blueproximity as this resolved it for them. I have done this and it has fixed the issue, I will now test again with a newer Kernal & blueproximity installed to see if it works fine or not.

Comment: Thanks to plugable support who have also provided excellent support with their product.